# Makefile for f2py in python3

Tags: python-3.x, makefile, cpython, f2py

In order to build extension modules using f2py in python2, I have been using a Makefile similar to:

```
default: fortran_lib.so

%.so::  %.f90
    f2py -c -m $* $<
```

For completeness, here is also a dummy `fortran_lib.f90` file

```
subroutine square(d)
implicit none
!f2py intent(inout) d
integer, intent(inout)  ::  d

d = d*d
end subroutine square
```

This used to work fine, `make` would simply produce `fortran_lib.so`.

Now I would like to support python3 as well, but when using `f2py3`, `make` produces the versioned `fortran_lib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` instead (on my particular setup).

Since this differs from the specified target name, `make` has no way of recognising that the target has already been made. Accordingly, it remakes the target every time you run `make`.

How do I get around this problem (without having to hardcode the version)?

- Can I tell f2py3 to turn off versioning?
- Can I somehow work around the versioning in the Makefile?
- Or am I forced to switch to other tools for building the extension modules (`distutils`,...)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My recommendation is to leave the versioning on (it was invented for a reason...) and instead work out what the suffix it uses is. The command `python3-config --extension-suffix` gets that.

Therefore the makefile looks like

```
EXT_SUFFIX := $(shell python3-config --extension-suffix)

default: fortran_lib$(EXT_SUFFIX)

%$(EXT_SUFFIX): %.f90
    f2py3 -c -m $* $<
```

(I'm not sure whether `shell` is a GNU extension and if so, whether it will reduce portability. That may be something to consider.)

---

If you're really keen on losing the suffix then you should probably just add a second step to the rule, something like:

```
%.so::  %.f90
    f2py3 -c -m $* $<
    mv $*$(EXT_SUFFIX) $@
```

If you don't want to use `shell` to get `EXT_SUFFIX` then you could probably come up with a wildcard that works.

I think this second option is worse that the first...

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Can't upvote yet due to rep<15.